# Slow Script when loading page

Tags: support, tex

Today i've recieved this error about 20 times:

> Safari is no longer responding because of a script on the webpage “Test the new \$LaTeX\$ markdown in this Sandbox question! - Electrical Engineering Meta - Stack Exchange” (http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/434/test-the-new-latex-markdown-in-this-sandbox-question). Do you want to stop running the script, or let it continue?

Has something changed on the site? From the looks of it if I click stop the page is fine but I haven't seen a small enough question that I can check for the minor details.

Its come up 3 times while writing this question and is getting annoying.

Answer (score 1):

We haven't changed anything, however, we do serve MathJax from their CDN as we are a major sponsoring partner:

- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/stack-exchange-partners-with-mathjax/
- http://www.mathjax.org/2011/06/14/news/mathjax-cdn-service-very-successful-2/

This means they can roll out new versions of MathJax at any time because the path points to their servers:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML"></script>`

Since nothing relevant that I can think of has changed on our end, I'd check and see if there is a new MathJax release out there -- for example, [1.1a went out on June 9th](http://www.mathjax.org/2011/06/10/news/mathjax-v1-1a-now-available/).